# Make HTML text have 2 colors without making new line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create HTML text that contains two colors (yellow and white), without creating a new line when switching colors. I have attempted to do this:

```
<p style="color:fc0;background-color:404040">Text Color Yellow <style="color:fff">Text Color White</p>
```

It doesn't work, as there is no `p` coming before the `style` element to change the color. 
My other way is to make two lines, but there is a bar of blank whitespace between the two lines of gray:

```
<p style="color:fc0;background-color:404040">Text Color Yellow</p> 
<p style="color:fff;background-color:404040">Text Color White</p>
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: CSS can be stupid just use basic HTML
<font color="YOUR COLOR">Text Color White</font>

No stupid  extra commands values paramaters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the white text in `span`. And, then set it's color property to white. This will work:

```
<p style="color:#fc0000;background-color:#404040">Text Color Yellow <span style="color:#ffffff">Text Color White</span></p>
```

**Note:** You are also missing `#` signs in color codes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are multiple ways you could do this. One quick way would be to use `<span>`:

```
<p>
  <span style="color:#ff0;background-color:#404040">Text Color Yellow</span>
  <span style="color:#fff;background-color:#404040">Text Color White</span>
</p>
```

Also, if you want to remove the line space in-between, you just need to put it in one line like this:

```
<p>
  <span class="yellow">Text Color Yellow</span><span class="white">Text Color White</span>
</p>
```

I separated the styles to make it shorter:

```
.yellow {
    color: #ff0;
  background-color: #404040;
  margin: 0;
}

.white {
    color: #fff;
  background-color: #404040;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use gradients for that but its better to have limited use or things get ugly.

this can be helpful https://cssgradient.io/blog/css-gradient-text/

Comment: I like your reference to the gradient, that is very helpful for future projects. However, I am wondering on how to make the text jump from yellow to white, rather than slowly ease to each color.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer will work correctly. But if you do not want to write any additional tags, try this:

```
<p style="color:#fc0;background-color:#404040;display:inline">Text Color Yellow</p> 
<p style="color:#fff;background-color:#404040;display:inline">Text Color White</p>
```

Comment: You forgot the `#` in the lines

Answer (score -1):

CSS can be stupid just use basic HTML

```
<font color="#FFFFFF">Text Color White</font>
```

No stupid new lines extra commands values parameters.